# Python Spyne change the name of _return values

Tags: web-services, python-2.7, spyne

I'm using python 2.7 and Spyne for creating some web services in Django.
I'm not able to change the name of the returned values, for example:
Given this code:

```
class Consumer(ServiceBase):
   @rpc(Integer,Integer, _returns = [Integer,Integer])
   def addConsumer(ctx, topic_id, consumer_id):
   ...
   ...
```

The response in my wsdl looks like:

```
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="addConsumerResult0" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
  <xs:element name="addConsumerResult1" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

I am looking for something that allow me to change name="addConsumerResult0" to name="whateverXYZ"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `_out_variable_names` to change return type names.

e.g.

```
class Consumer(ServiceBase):
   @rpc(Integer,Integer, _returns = [Integer,Integer], 
                                      _out_variable_names=["whateverXYZ", "foo"])
   def addConsumer(ctx, topic_id, consumer_id):
   ...
   ...
```